# Cache drupal system pages

Tags: drupal, caching, drupal-7

Is there a way to cache drupal system pages (e.g. taxonomy/term/%, forum/%, node) for **authorized users** without core haking?

Answer (score 1):

For drupal 6 there is http://drupal.org/project/authcache. I don't believe there is a module for drupal 7 that is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire up the [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu_alter/6) on your custom module, and from there you can do whatever you want with that path (taxonomy/term/%).

Check what is the function callback for those paths. For example:

```
mysql>
select * from menu_router where path like '%taxonomy/term/%';
```

It says that the page callback is [taxonomy_term_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.pages.inc/function/taxonomy_term_page/6). You don't need to copy all that code into your custom function, all you need to do is something like this:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Route taxonomy/term/% to my custom caching function.
  $items['taxonomy/term/%']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_cached_taxonomy_term_page';
}

function mymodule_cached_taxonomy_term_page($term) {
  // Retrieve from persistent cache.
  $cache = cache_get('taxonomy_term_'. $term); 

  // If data hasn't expired from cache.
  if(!empty($cache->data) && ($cache->created < $cache->expire)) {
    return $cache->data;
  } else {
  // Else rebuild the cache.
    $term_page = taxonomy_term_page($term);
    cache_set('taxonomy_term_'. $term, $term_page, 'cache_page', strtotime('+30 minute'));
    return $term_page;
  }
}
```

If going down this path, you will want to get familiarized with [cache_get](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_get/6) and [cache_set](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_set/6). You might want to also check out Lullabot's excellent caching [article](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-caching-data).

You can follow the same approach for forum/%, node, and everything else you want. Happy caching!

Comment: I've thought about this way. But taxonomy_term_page not only returns the html page code, it also creates breadcrumbs and adds feed.
It will not work in  mymodule_cached_taxonomy_term_page. Other callback functions additionaly can use drupal_set_title, drupal_add_js, drupal_add_css and so on.

Comment: I know, I saw the taxonomy_term_page code as well =(. How about if you don't cache the results of taxonomy_term_page like I suggested above, how about if you drill down into that function, and selectively copy into the custom function the code that you need, then call separately the feeds function? Have you tried that? Let us know what you found.

Comment: Yes I have used similar code for taxonomy_term_page. It works fine. Now I am looking for solution to cache other core pages (node, node/%, forum). I don't want to move all drupal core callback functions to my module. )

Comment: As far as drupal core output caching, Drupal has you covered for anonymous users ([setup](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/03/speed_drupal_web_site_enabling_page_caching#HowtoenableDrupalpagecaching)). As for authenticated users, then I would try what @mizru recommended ([authcache](http://drupal.org/project/authcache)).

Comment: More helpful information: http://2bits.com/articles/drupal-core-caching-and-contributed-content-caching-modules.html